# find and rm -rf, why it prints errors?

Tags: find, rm

I'm definitely doing something wrong but can't figure this one out.  When I run `rm -rf` on directories through `find` I get a `No such file or directory` but it does not happen when I do it manually.  Assuming the following directory tree:

```
[~]$ mkdir -p blueprints/blog
[~]$ find
.
./blueprints
./blueprints/blog
```

I create directories and add files to them:

```
[~]$ mkdir ./blueprints/blog/__pycache__ ./blueprints/__pycache__ ./__pycache__
[~]$ touch ./blueprints/blog/__pycache__/dummy.pyc ./__pycache__/dummy.pyc
```

I am sure I have them:

```
[~]$ find . -type d -name '__pycache__'
./blueprints/blog/__pycache__
./blueprints/__pycache__
./__pycache__
```

But removing them causes find to print an error:

```
[~]$ find . -type d -name '__pycache__' -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: ‘./blueprints/blog/__pycache__’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./blueprints/__pycache__’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./__pycache__’: No such file or directory
```

They get removed alright but what is happening there?

---

Doing it in a different way does not provoke the error:

```
[~]$ mkdir ./blueprints/blog/__pycache__ ./blueprints/__pycache__ ./__pycache__
[~]$ touch ./blueprints/blog/__pycache__/dummy.pyc ./__pycache__/dummy.pyc
[~]$ find . -type d -name '__pycache__' -exec echo rm -rf {} \; | sh
```

---

**Why does find report that error?**  As far as I am aware if `-exec` is present the `-print` action does not get invoked (that's what I suspected at first).

I have replicated the above using both find 4.6.0 and find 4.5.11

Comment: Does adding `-depth` help?

Comment: @iruvar - yeah, it does!  I get it now, find executes `-exec` and *then* tries to walk deeper into the `__pycache__` directory.  You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you delete the directory with `rm -rf`, `find` still tries to enter it after deleting it (it has no notion of what `rm` is doing). That's where the error happens.

You should add the `-depth` flag.

From [the POSIX `find` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> `-depth`
>
> The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause descent of the directory hierarchy to be done so that all entries in a directory are acted on before the directory itself. If a `-depth` primary is not specified, all entries in a directory shall be acted on after the directory itself. If any `-depth` primary is specified, it shall apply to the entire expression even if the `-depth` primary would not normally be evaluated.

Comment: That's what I get from not reading the man with enough attention.  Thanks