# find . - exec rm -rf {} and strange messages that the files were not found

Tags: find, directory, rm

I have a script for creating backups and deleting old backups. It has this line:

```
 find . -type d -mtime +29 -user admin -name "20*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This way, directories with backups older than 29 days are deleted.
This works, directories are deleted, but this message is displayed every time:

```
find: `./2020-06-16-23-30': No such file or directory
```

(the date changes in the message)

Please tell me why this message appears and how to correct the script.

Using output redirection (`>/dev/null 2>&1`) is not suitable for me, because I would like to see messages about some real errors.

This is a directory listing with backups:

```
$ cd /volume1/Backup && ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 19 23:30 2020-06-19-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 20 23:30 2020-06-20-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 21 23:30 2020-06-21-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 22 23:30 2020-06-22-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 23 23:30 2020-06-23-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 24 23:30 2020-06-24-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 25 23:30 2020-06-25-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 26 23:30 2020-06-26-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 27 23:30 2020-06-27-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 28 23:30 2020-06-28-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 29 23:30 2020-06-29-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jun 30 23:30 2020-06-30-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  1 23:30 2020-07-01-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  2 23:30 2020-07-02-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  3 23:30 2020-07-03-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  4 23:30 2020-07-04-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  5 23:30 2020-07-05-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  6 23:30 2020-07-06-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  7 23:30 2020-07-07-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  8 23:30 2020-07-08-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul  9 23:30 2020-07-09-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul 10 23:30 2020-07-10-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul 11 23:30 2020-07-11-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul 12 23:30 2020-07-12-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul 13 23:30 2020-07-13-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul 14 23:30 2020-07-14-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul 15 23:30 2020-07-15-23-30
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin users       4096 Jul 16 23:30 2020-07-16-23-30
```

Comment: Do you have a tree of directories, or just a single level?

Comment: Related: [find and rm -rf, why it prints errors?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345842/find-and-rm-rf-why-it-prints-errors)

Comment: At the moment, there are no nested directories inside directories whose names are dates with time, but I think they may appear. And now I realized that I can use -maxdepth 1 parameter for find ) Thank you! )

Comment: `find` has a much smarter `-delete` option built-in. It is way faster, needs no external processes, and does not trip over its own feet like -exec rm does.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a race-condition:

Suppose you have a file `/a/b/c` and you run `find /a -exec rm -rf {} \;`

In some cases (not always) things will happen it this order

1. `find` will notice that `/a/b` and `/a/b/c` exist and remember them both
2. It will launch `rm -rf /a/b` which will delete both `/a/b` and `/a/b/c`
3. It will not know that `/a/b/c` is gone, it will still try to delete this (non-existing) file and you will get that error.

Possible solutions:

- What you could do: Use regexps to filter lines ending with `No such file or directory` out
- What would probably be better: (Test it first by placing `echo` in front of `rm -rf`):

```
find . -type d -mtime +29 -user admin -name "20*" > /tmp/list_of_dirs
perl -ne 'system("rm -rf $_") < /tmp/list_of_dirs
```

- What I myself would do: I would not consider this as a real problem. If `rm` would break on some dirs, you will probably notice it...

Comment: A simple way is to just use `find . -depth ...`. The error is not shown because the whole command tries to _delete_ a file that is gone, but because `find` tries  to descend into a directory after deleting it. `-depth` tells `find` to process the content of directories before the directories themselves.

Comment: I have to admit that that kind of race condition is more likely.