# error: linux "find" finds/renames not all directories containing string at first run

Tags: find, rename

I run `find` on a file structure (several hundreds of folders, about 4 layers deep) with commands like: `find "/media/$disk/_all" -depth -type d -exec/execdir rename -d 's/ 1000k/ [1000k]/' "{}" \;`. I noted repeatedly that some occurrences of folders containing  1000k remain unrenamed, I noted some of them got renamed on second run of the command. Why not all on the first run?

Also, I noted often output has "Can't rename /media/some_original /media/some_renamed: No such file or directory", after that I check and some_original got successfully renamed to some_renamed.

First error in my guess occurs due to find not going through all tree, second is due to find going and invoking exec twice for some/all? entries. I added -depth option later to be sure of "child" folder being renamed before "parent", but it did not help (and in my case I have not noted several levels due to be renamed anyway when I noted the error).

I was not able to find answer via web search. What could be the issue here?

System is Linux Mint 20.1.

Added: I've checked I have not found any links in the structure, using ls -lR /path/to/folder | grep ^l from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513133/how-do-i-find-all-of-the-symlinks-in-a-directory-tree.

Disk is mounted like that: type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,stripe=8191,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: renaming files will reorder the directory that may lead to some results not being found.

Comment: @Jasen, thank you, have not thought about it. I thought about it SQL, nodes wise, like go through all nodes in a folder by id and assumed renaming a node would not change its order/id, cause I'm not sorting by name. Do you know of any bash-using way to fix that?

Comment: (1) `I added -depth option later to be sure of "parent" folder being renamed before "child"` – `-depth` does the opposite: deeper directories are processed first. And it's the right thing to do when renaming with `find`. (2) What is the filesystem? Is it FUSE? See "Simultaneous Access and Race Conditions" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1242432/432690). I think `find` does its things sequentially, so it shouldn't(?) trigger "simultaneous access" in this context. But if the filesystem is FUSE then maybe the implementation is somewhat buggy in the first place. (3) Can you provide MCVE?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, thank you. Child first - I thought about it, just wrote here incorrectly, fixed now. MCVE - what is it? Could not quickly web-search it. I added mount line, drive is in USB attached box.

Comment: [Minimal complete verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659). In this case it could be a sequence of `mkdir -p` commands to create a directory structure prone to the issue; finally the `find` command you have already posted. (4) If you manage to find MCVE then also tell us if you can always replicate the problem with it. Or does the problem occur randomly?

Comment: I don't think `type ext4` (is it the output from `mount`?) is FUSE, it looks like regular ext4 handled by the kernel. There is FUSE for ext4 but it reports `type fuse.ext4` (at least in Ubuntu). When you say "should be using FUSE", do you know this? or are you guessing?

Comment: I added quotes to your code (mainly because of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)). Please verify if the code is still what you intended it to be.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, just recalled I plug-in USB and something I've read about FUSE. Could have been wrong. I added example for part of the issue. Will try to make more examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122877/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-martian2020).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Preliminary notes

- This answer is an attempt to explain what may have happened, not a firm explanation what happened for sure. This is because:

  - the OP has tried different variants of the command (with or without `-depth`, with `-exec` or `-execdir`), the exact command posted in the body of the question should be taken with a grain of salt;
  - each try possibly modified the directory tree, but there is no log stating what renaming happen because of what exact command;
  - similarly there is no log of errors;
  - after analyzing the problem (in comments and chat) we noticed there are few different issues that generate similar error messages (and therefore it's easy to assume there is just one issue).

  For these reasons an attempt to create a single [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659) (in a form of one exact directory tree and one exact `find` command) failed. We agreed it will be the best to create an answer that covers possible issues, with future readers in mind. This answer is such answer.
- There is [more than one `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618). The syntax in question works with `rename` being a Perl script associated with Larry Wall and Robin Barker. I assume this is the `rename` used. The issues covered in this answer are not specific to this particular `rename` though.

---

#### What may have happened

There at few different issues that can generate `No such file or directory` when you use `find` with `rename`.

First, let's simplify the example. Let the directory structure be:

```
/a/b/c.1/c.2/d
```

and the command be:

```
find /a/b -exec rename s/c/X/ {} \;
```

This command will yield:

```
find: '/a/b/c.1': No such file or directory
```

This is because without `-depth` `find` processes `c.1` before it tries to descend to `c.2`. When processing `c.1`, `rename` renames it to `X.1`, but `find` is not aware the name changes. It tries to work with `c.1` in order to process deeper files but `c.1` no longer exists. This is very similar to [using `find` with `rm -r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345845/108618).

The second iteration of the command will see `/a/b/X.1/c.2/d` and successfully rename `c.2` to `X.2`. Nevertheless it will complain about `c.2` not being there. The third iteration will do nothing and complain about nothing.

You need to tell `find` to process files in a directory before doing anything to the directory itself. This is what `-depth` is for.

---

Even with `-depth` there may still be problems. Again, having this structure:

```
/a/b/c.1/c.2/d
```

and running the "fixed" command:

```
find /a/b -depth -exec rename s/c/X/ {} \;
```

we will get:

```
Can't rename /a/b/c.1/c.2/d /a/b/X.1/c.2/d: No such file or directory
Can't rename /a/b/c.1/c.2 /a/b/X.1/c.2: No such file or directory
```

It's not immediately obvious the messages come from `rename` but they do. The problem is `d` is processed first and `rename` wants to change `/a/b/c.1/c.2/d` into `/a/b/X.1/c.2/d`. It's like `mv /a/b/c.1/c.2/d /a/b/X.1/c.2/d`, you cannot do this if `/a/b/X.1/c.2/` does not exist. And later (while processing `c.2`) you cannot `mv /a/b/c.1/c.2 /a/b/X.1/c.2` because `X.1` does not exist (yet).

<sup>(You may be surprised `rename` by default tries something that cannot succeed. Note `mv /a/b/c.1/c.2/d /a/b/X.1/c.2/d` cannot succeed when `X.1` doesn't exist. Still this command is sane when `X.1/c.2/` already exists along `c.1/c.2/`. The default behavior of `rename` is equally sane in this case.)</sup>

In our case `X.1` appears when `c.2` is silently renamed to `X.1` but this happens later. The second iteration of the command will complain while processing `d`, it will manage to rename `c.2`. The third iteration will do nothing and complain about nothing.

Note if you had `/c.0` instead of `/a` and the command was `find /c.0/b …` then no `rename` would succeed and any number of iterations would be futile.

The problem is `rename s/c/X/` tries to change the first `c` in the path, even if this `c` is in a directory component, not exactly in the filename. There are at least two ways to deal with this.

---

You can use `rename -d`. This option makes `rename` act on the filename only. The following command:

```
find /c.0/b -depth -exec rename -d s/c/X/ {} \;
```

will successfully change `/c.0/b/c.1/c.2/d` into `/c.0/b/X.1/X.2/d` (so even `c.0` is not a problem).

`-d` is a relatively new option. In general your `rename` may not support it. In such case use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`:

```
find /c.0/b -depth -execdir rename s/c/X/ {} \;
```

<sup>(In general your `find` may or may not support `-execdir`.)</sup>

It works because when processing `d`, the string `rename` processes is now `./d`, not `/c.0/b/c.1/c.2/d`; similarly when processing `c.2`, it's `./c.2`, not `/c.0/b/c.1/c.2`. The tool works in the respective parent directory each time, so the relative paths work. By not including the full path in the string, we get the behavior of `rename -d` without `-d`.

Well, almost. If you want `rename` to do something with dots (e.g. change `c.2` into `c-2` etc.) then the leading dot in `./d` or `./c.2` is something you need to deal with. With `-d` there is no such problem, regardless if you use `-exec` or `-execdir`; so use `rename -d` if you can.

---

#### Final note

The command in question includes `-depth` and `rename -d`. The OP explicitly stated:

> I added `-depth` option later […]

so probably the lack of `-depth` was the initial problem. But then:

> [adding `-detph`] did not help

Considering this and noting the error (`Can't rename …`) comes from `rename`, I conclude `-d` was also not always there or I'm missing something. For now I think `find -depth` along with `rename -d` should be robust. Assuming it really failed for the OP, I cannot explain this (yet).